# git clone from remote server with ssh chaining

Tags: git, ssh

we have a git repository on remove server A. I normally access that via ssh from my work machine, e.g.

```
git clone user@A:/path/to/repo
```

However, A is not accessible directly from outside work. There is another server, B, which I ssh into, which can then ssh into A. What I want to do now is to clone the repository on my machine at home. I tried stuff like

```
git clone B:A:/path/to/repo
git clone user@B:A/path/to/repo
```

neither of which worked. I suppose I could copy the repo on B and clone from there, but merging changes back to A would be a hassle. Any suggestions how I can access A directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have passwordless SSH setup between server A and server B, then you can write a simple wrapper script which connects to server A via SSH and runs the command SSH with the arguments from Git.

Create Script:

```
cat << EOF > ssh-wrapper.sh
#!/bin/sh
ssh -T serverB.example.com ssh ${@}
exit $?
EOF
chmod 755 ssh-wrapper.sh
```

Then set GIT_SSH to ./ssh-wrapper.sh and call Git:

```
GIT_SSH='./ssh-wrapper.sh' git clone user@A:/path/to/repo
```

Comment: Great, thanks. A quick note to readers: commit using the standard syntax , e.g. "git commit -m ". Push by specifying the path to the wrapper: GIT_SSH='./ssh-wrapper.sh' git push

Comment: I needed to invoke ruby's bundler with a specific deploy key. After ages of searching I finally found the magic env variable in your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a SSH-Tunnel to make it through A.
Take a look at this:
http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html